# How to preset file format for document-based core data application's save-dialog to sqlite?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, nspersistentdocument

I started a document-based core data application targeting 10.9-only from the corresponding Xcode 5.1 template.

When the save-dialog is opened from the file-menu of my application, the user is presented with three file format options: Binary, SQLite, XML.

I don't want to give the user this choice but instead preset the file format to SQLite and no longer present the options in the save-dialog.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it is as easy as removing the *XML* and *Binary* entries from *Document Types* in my `Application-Info.plist`. Can anyone confirm this?